# HTML Form with Required Fields, Confirmation Dialog box, and Submission Summary

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit, form-submit

1. I have an HTML form that uses a PHP file in the form tag **action=""** for sending the content of the form as an email.
2. I have a simple JavaScript for required fields that is called for in the form tag **onsubmit=""**.
3. My PHP file returns a summary of the form after it is submitted.

All I need to add is a simple confirmation dialog box. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. (Sorry, I should be a little more brilliant!) I could probably add JavaScript to my required fields code, but not sure how to do that. Here is my existing code:

```
function validate_required(field,alerttxt)
{
with (field)
{
if (value==null||value=="")
{
alert(alerttxt);return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
}

function validate_form(thisform)
{
with (thisform)
{
if (validate_required(drop_point,"Please choose a Drop Point")==false)
{drop_point.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(your_name,"Please enter your Name")==false)
{your_name.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(email,"Please enter your Email Address")==false)
{your_name.focus();return false;}
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to double check on server side ; doing only javascript checking is not safe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just need a simple response so they don't submit the order by accident. JavaScript will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoban got me going and here is what my solution is:

```
function validate_form(thisform)
{
with (thisform)
{
if (validate_required(drop_point,"Please choose a Drop Point")==false)
{drop_point.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(first_name,"Please enter your First Name")==false)
{first_name.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(last_name,"Please enter your Last Name")==false)
{last_name.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(drop_point_date,"Please enter the Drop Point Date")==false)
{drop_point_date.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(email,"Please enter your Email Address")==false)
{email.focus();return false;}
if (validate_required(order_confirm,"Please confirm your order")==false)
{order_confirm.focus();return false;}
}
return confirm("Do you want to submit the form");
}
```

And that works perfect!

Thanks a lot! Live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?");
```

It returns True or False based on Users choice

Some samples [here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php). Is this what you are looking for?

Edit:

```
function validate_required(field,alerttxt)
{
   with (field)
        {
         if (value==null||value=="")
            {
              alert(alerttxt);return false;
            }

        }
return confirm("Are you want to submit the form");
}
```

Comment: I think that might work (had seen that page earlier)...would I need to put my PHP page in as the page it would redirect to if True? And if false, then what? (I don't need all those extra dialog/alert boxes that the script makes on that page...just dismiss the dialop box). And to run 2 JavaScripts in the Form tag onsubmit="", do I separate them with && ? I had tried briefly, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can dd this to the Validateform function.. If all the required fieds are entered then you return true already in your function.. Just beofre that you can show the confirmation box and then return true or false....Clear?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you show me where I would add the confirm() code?

Comment: Edited you code lil it.. Check and let me know... Not tested ;-)